# jqGrid Column Sorting Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid displaying the data in the table correctly and on gridComplete when the table loads, it applies some click functions to some icons in certain table cells on each row. When the table initially loads, all the functions work properly, but when I click a column header and sort a column in either asc or desc order, the table sorts the rows and then the click functions no longer work. Has anybody run into this issue using jqGrid before? I am using pagination with the table and when i go to the next page, the click functions work again until I sort a column. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*I forgot to mention before that I also have a subgrid for each row that is collapsed and will expand when an arrow icon is clicked on at the beginning of the row.

Comment: According to the documentation the gridComplete event should fire after sorting as well, so it looks like we'll need to see the code to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Zikes, the gridComplete function will run again if you have your datatype set to json or xml, but i manually set my datatype to local so I only sort the current dataset instead of making a new server call and sorting server side. I only change the datatype to json when i interact with the pager.

Comment: According to the documentation at http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events it says it will fire independent of the datatype parameter and after sorting and paging.  Please post your code (or the relevant subset) so we can help you figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. When I created the table, I added a small div element that was hidden at the bottom of the main table div element that holds all the data. The small div slides up and down with setting options inside of it. When you sort the table, the jqgrid seems to sort the table and place it within the div inside of the main table. Since it probably doesn't specify what div to put the sorted data back into, it places it into both div elements. When i sorted the data and looked at the smaller div, the sorting recreated the table within the small div as well. So, I ended up with two tables, my original and the new one within the small div. This messed up my java scripts, because the references were all jacked up at that point. So, my solution was to remove the small div when sorting and then when the sorting finished, recreate the small div so the sorting function doesn't get confused. Also, Zikes, the gridComplete function does not run on sort for me. I put an alert statement within the gridComplete function and it shows when the table is loaded initially, but when you sort a column it never shows. I placed the alert at the very beginning of the function, so I know it wasn't running. Either the documentation you are looking at is incorrect or i have some sort of setting that disables the gridComplete function from running on sort. Thanks for the input.